# Putnam: Show that $a(n)=b(n+2)$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math

Let $a(n)$ be the number of representations of positive integer $n$ as a sum of 1's and 2's taking order into account.

$$ \text{Example $n=4$:  } (1+1+1+1), (1+2+1),(1+1+2),(2+1+1),(2+2)\implies a(4)=5$$

Let $b(n)$ be the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of integers $>1$.
$$ \text{Example $n=6$:  } (3+3), (2+2+2),(4+2),(2+4),(6)\implies b(6)=5$$

Prove that $a(n)=b(n+2)$ and find a one-to-one correspondence between them.

Comment: By the way, $a(n)$ is the $(n+1)$th Fibonacci number. It's fairly easy to see that both the $a$s and the $b$s satisfy the recurrence $f(n+2)=f(n+1)+f(n)$.

Comment: That's interesting, I did not see this at all.  I will try and convince myself that $a(n)$ is the $(n+1)$ Fibonacci number.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a sum with summands $>1$, syntactically replace a summand $k$ with a sequence of $k$ times "1", then replace any occurance of "1+1" with "2". Remove the first and last "1" and insert "+" signs.
For example
$$3+3\mapsto 111+111\mapsto 11211\mapsto 121\mapsto 1+2+1 $$
$$2+2+2\mapsto 11+11+1\mapsto 1221\mapsto 22\mapsto 2+2 $$
$$4+2\mapsto 1111+11\mapsto 11121\mapsto 112\mapsto 1+1+2 $$
$$2+4\mapsto 11+1111\mapsto 12111\mapsto 211\mapsto 2+1+1 $$
$$6\mapsto 111111\mapsto 111111\mapsto 1111\mapsto 1+1+1+1 $$
I guess you see how this method is reversible